# Phantom JS installation on Shared hosting hostmonster

Tags: php, phantomjs, hostmonster

I am trying to install Phantom JS on shared hosting. My hosting is Hostmonster. And the process is as described pretty simple that just copy the PhantomJS binary file on the server and then u can execute it. 
Locally it is working perfect. But on the server it is not running. 
Can anyone please guide in detail.

Comment: In what ways is it not working? Bad file path?

Comment: nope. The php file I run it through is working fine as I echo some messages for debugging. Messages are running before that and also after that. But the command is not being executed. It has to generate a pdf. I also checked the rights and permissions. And they r given 777

Comment: Can you run it from the shell?

Comment: Locally I run it through exec() function in php

Comment: Have you find a solution ? I'm trying to do exactly the same thing !